# Media Query for Samsung Galaxy

Tags: css, media-queries

I have media queries and for all devices, you can see it [here](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/qKjroP), in **CSS** - 
and here without all the elements...

```
/* 
##Device = Desktops
##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops */

@media (min-width: 80.0625em) {
  ......
}

/* 
##Device = Laptops, Desktops
##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px */
@media (min-width:  64.0625em) and (max-width: 80em) {
  ............
}

 /* 
 ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
 ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px  */


@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) 
                   and (max-width: 64em) 
                   and (orientation: portrait) {
   ............................
}

 /* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1023px
 */

@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 64em) and (orientation: landscape) {

      ....................
}

 /* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
    ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 41.75em) and (max-width: 47.9375em) {  
   ..............
}

  /* für iPhone 6/7/8  766,4px x 375px   */


@media only screen and (max-width: 47.9em) 
                    and (min-width: 23.4375em) 
                    and (orientation: landscape)    {

   ...............................
}

   /* kleine smartphone   Landscape  640px  x 319px kleine als Galaxy S5  */


@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)      {

     ..................................
}

    /* iphone 5 und kleine  528px     */

@media only screen and (max-width: 33em) and (orientation: landscape) {     

         ......................
}
   /* ich selb gebaut   767px x 481px     

@media only screen and (max-width: 30.0625em) and (orientation: portrait) {  

      ...................
}
    /*  iphone 5       galaxy S5  */


@media only screen and (max-width: 23em) and (orientation: portrait) {   

  .......................
}
```

My problem is with Samsung Galaxy off **A 50** and **Landscape**, till **A 40**, **landscape** and **portrait**, working gut, but off **A 50**, only **portrait** working.

Can anyone help me and give me an idea how I can remedy this problem?

Comment: It's well past time to give up trying to correlate device resolution to device model. Just adapt your design to the available space.

Comment: As @HereticMonkey has already mentioned, this is an outdated approach. Generally speaking, phone models are incredibly awkward to define and identify using CSS  - best practices now are to create a reactive/adaptive approach that can adapt to any device (mobile, tablet and web etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for Media Query for Samsung Galaxy off A 50 **landscape** .

I add:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 55.75em) {
   .......................
}
```

betwixt

```
@media (min-width: 48em) and (max-width: 64em) and (orientation: landscape) {

  ....................
}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 41.75em) and (max-width: 47.9375em) {  
 ..............
}
```

I was at a shopping centre and locking many Smartphone, and the majority of them can see my website gut.... I think the best solution for this problem is making smaller the difference between  Media Queries on `max-width`.